# How to specify a column to be of bool type

Tags: c#, sql

If I want to do something like:

```
select name, 0 as ischild from people
```

and specify the ischild column I just made on-the-fly to be a bool column (for later use), how can I do that? Since right now if I read this result set from C# code it always interprets 0 as int, which gives error if I do GetBoolean.

Besides that, if I do something further like:

```
select * from otherpeople left outer join 
(select *, cast(0 as bit) as ischild from People) q on otherpeople.id = q.id
```

Now some rows of ischild might be null right? Would should I do if I still want to use GetBoolean on that column?

Comment: @thudbutt Sorry, name should be *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select name, cast(0 as bit) as ischild from people
```

**Edit**

For extended question

Bool has two states -> TRUE or FALSE. However into database you can have TRUE, FALSE OR NULL

If you want to consider NULL as false, then instead of casting in inner query I would prefer casting in outer query

```
select otherpeople.*, q.*, cast(ISNULL(q.isChild, 0) AS BIT) AS isChild 
from otherpeople left outer join 
(select *, 0 as ischild from People) q on otherpeople.id = q.id
```

Comment: Could you answer my further question.. Sorry I didn't come up with that in my first edition..

Comment: Now the question you raised is nice and tricky. Because bool has only two states either true or false while database also has NULL. Its a question to you now, How do you want to interpret this NULL as true or false or you want to handle in C# as DBNULL?

Comment: I want it to be false

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT name, CAST(0 AS BIT) AS ischild FROM people
```

If you want to include this as part of an outer join where you may potentially get null values then you will need to check for nulls before GetBoolean. You can do this by calling IsDBNull on the column.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx for an example

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("ischild")))
               Console.Write(" {0}", reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("ischild")));
```

Comment: @Xufeng - I've added an example of coping with nulls

Answer (score 3):

```
select name, CAST(0 AS BIT) as ischild from people
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
select name, CAST(0 AS BIT) as ischild from people
```